# For what values of k is in the span and is linearly independent of the vector

Tags: linear-algebra

What does it mean to be in the span of and what is linear independency? It is particularly confusing that I have a variable.

I have row reduced the matrix to:

[1 0 7
0 1 -3
0 0 (k-5)]

I am asked for what values of k is in the span. Do I just set k-5 = 0?
Then I am asked for what values of k is the set linearly independent. But it is my understanding that since the last column is a free variable, then this means the set is linearly dependent?

Comment: Yes, when $k=5$, the third row vector would become a linear combination of the first two, making the set of vectors linearly dependent. When $k\ne5$, the rank of the matrix will be non-zero, indicating that the set of vectors is independent.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Linear Independency

Vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ are said to be linearly independent if

$$
c_1v_1+\ldots + c_nv_n=0
$$

has only trivial solution

$$
c_1 = c_2 = \ldots = c_n = 0
$$

where $c_i$ are scalars from the underlying field.

### Span

For a subset $S \subset V$ of a vector space $V$, the span of $S$ is the set of all linear combinations of vectors in $S$.

If a vector $v$ is i the span of $S$, then there are vectors $s_1, \ldots, s_l \in S$ and coefficients $c_1, \ldots, c_l$ in the scalar field such that $v$ is the linear combination

$$
v = c_1s_1 + \ldots + c_ls_l
$$

but that means, that

$$
0 = c_1s_1 + \ldots + c_ls_l - v
$$

and thus the vectors are linearly dependent.

---

For your matrix it means:

1. The vector parametrised with $k$ is in the span of the others if the rank of the extended matrix doesn't change (because the added vector is a linear combination of the other vectors).
2. The vectors are linearly independent if the matrix has full rank.

With this you see that for $k=5$, the last row becomes zero, and the matrix has rank 2, is not of full rank. That means the added vectors is a linear combination of the other two. Which means, it is in their span.

If $k \not= 5$, then the matrix has rank 3. And the vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: So, k is in the span for all values that k ≠ 5?

Comment: The parameter $k$ is in no span. The vector you add [the one with $k$ i suppose] is in the span of the other two if $k=5$. For all other values of $k$ they are lin. independent.

Comment: I thought since k is included in the vector it would just be a number not a parameter. I appreciate your help

Comment: That is a matter of perspective. You get a different vector for each $k$, and with it a different matrix. I like to think of it the way that $k$ parametrises the vector and with it the matrix.